# Add site name in mobile nav bar in wordpress theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I`ve installed WordPress theme to my site and I wish to add site name in mobile nav bar near toggle button like on this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/byVzb.png
but as you can see it is not centered, how can I center it vertically.
Also, you can view it in my site http://grants.purple.kz

My HTML code

```
<div class="menu-mobile">
        <div class="trigger-nav">
            <div class="trigger-icon nav-toogle menu-mobile-toogle">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="icon-bar top"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar middle"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar bottom"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="font-size:150%; color:white; margin-left:60px"><?=get_bloginfo('name')?></div>
        <div class="trigger-nav-right">
            <ul class="nav-right-options">
                <li>
                    <span class="icon-search">
                        <i class="thememattic-icon ion-ios-search"></i>
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="site-logo site-logo-mobile" href="<?php echo esc_url(get_home_url()); ?>">
                        <i class="thememattic-icon ion-ios-home-outline"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So what can I do for center site name by vertical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: This should do it.

```
<div style="font-size:150%;color:white;margin-left:60px;margin-top: -7px;">Grants</div>
```

Add: `margin-top: -7px;`

Is this what you are asking? This might not be the best way. But, this should do the job.